# FlexPrintJob pause Flex code execution

Tags: apache-flex, printing

when using `FlexPrintJob`, after calling `start()`, a OS system print interface will appear, and at the same time Flex code execution will be paused, and it will remain paused until user finished interaction with the OS print dialog. the problem is I do have data from server, and the connection will time out within certain period, so is there any walk around to not pause the Flex code execution while OS print dialog is popped up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc for `FlexPrintJob`:

> You use the FlexPrintJob class to print a dynamically rendered document that you format specifically for printing.

This makes me wonder if you couldn't (essentially) fork off a second page from the browser that contains your print job and do the printing from there. This would leave your original page still running. In my flex apps I do this via PHP (create additional pages for printing and such). Example [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/29/launching-new-browser-windows-from-flex/).

Otherwise: you should finish all the server data d/l before starting the print job to avoid this issue.

Flex is only just recently starting to add multi-threading. It's adding worker threads of a sort but this won't help what you're asking for.